# Democracy Index rating of EU?

Tags: european-union, democracy, europe, measurement

Would it be difficult to measure the EU by the Democracy Index, seeing as the EU has a parliament, elections, laws, a currency, a supreme court and a central bank?

What challenges are there for the measures of democracy of the EU's for *Electoral process and pluralism, Functioning of government,    Political-participation, Political culture, Civil liberties*?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index

The index is [composed of 60 questions (page 9)](https://www.economist.com/media/pdf/DEMOCRACY_INDEX_2007_v3.pdf), can't the word "nation" be replaced with "Union"/"EU" and the questions answered by experts? If the EU has judiciary and a legislative branch, and all the hallmarks of a nation then the questions can be phrased to apply, i.e.:

2. Are elections for the EU
   legislature and head of the EU fair?
   1: No major irregularities in
   the voting process
   0.5: Significant irregularities
   occur (intimidation, fraud),
   but do not affect significantly the overall outcome
   0: Major irregularities occur
   and affect the outcome

Answer (score 8):

The challenge would be the very fractured *political culture* and legal and political system. There is a supreme court, but various national supreme courts reserve some powers (even if exercising them would fracture the EU). There is no unified election system for the parliament.

Comment: The political culture of all the member states is known, and the MEP's and regional treaties and voting systems are known. I still don't understand why those elements cannot be quantified by the measures of the index. The Index seems like a good way of measuring unclear and fractured bureaucracy, it implies that there could be more information on and accountability of election system. The courts aren't more difficult to measure than american state and federal judiciary.

Comment: Mostly the questions are of the nature: 11. Is potential access to public
office open to all citizens?
1: Yes
0.5: Formally unrestricted, but
in practice restricted for
some groups, or for citizens from some parts of the
country
0: No .... The questions of the index can be found here: https://www.economist.com/media/pdf/DEMOCRACY_INDEX_2007_v3.pdf Just replace the words "the nation" with "The EU" and the questions can be answered by experts and by the population.

Comment: @com.prehensible, take 21, 22, 23. The answers could differ from country to country. 10. Also country-specific. 17. Extremely interesting for the smaller ones.And so on. And for the EU as a whole, the fairness of elections is also questionable. I understand that *fair* elections should be *equal*, not with different rules for different parts of the electorate.

Comment: @O.m. don't places like the US have different rules for different parts of the electorate? How presidential electors are assigned being the most obvious.

Comment: @Jontia, a rule which says "two electors per state, plus more depending on population" is the same for the entire US. It would be more problematical if states beginning with 'A' got extra electors.

Comment: I was thinking more of the states that bind electors, those that split electors and the interstate popular vote pact as the differences rather than the number of electors per head.

Comment: @o.m. For local government issues, the result can be a weighted average of the local government index scores. for the centralized union government, it's democracy should be better than the local governments.

Comment: @com.prehensible, one could also argue that the total score should be the *lowest* of any local government. But that would make single polities and combined ones like the EU hard to compare.